# Controlling rectangular geom_ribbon in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot, and am trying to add a ribbon in the form of a simple rectangle to a barplot I have. The idea is to show a cutoff below a certain value.

The barplot is fine but I can't quite get the ribbon right - I'd like it displayed a little wider but it seems to be limited to the width of the barplot data.

I tried using `xmin` and `xmax` but that doesn't increase the width of the shaded area.

Is there a way of explicitly controlling the width of `geom_ribbon`?

```
# Where df is a data frame containing the data to plot
library(cowplot)

ggplot(df, aes(x=treatments, y=propNotEliminated)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(xmin=0, xmax=21, ymin=0, ymax=20)) +  # the xmin and xmax don't do what I'd expect
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="white", colour="black", size=1) +
  theme_cowplot()
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Why don't you use `geom_hline` for displaying the cutoff? Seems more logical to me.

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought too, but I have two other properties I need to display as lines (not shown here for clarity) so adding a third makes things look a bit cluttered - a shaded area, probably displayed a bit lighter than it is at the moment, should be clearer.

Comment: I see your point. Another option could be using lines with different colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `geom_rect`?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, fill = "blue") + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 1, xmax = 3, ymin = 1, ymax = 2, fill = "red") + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 1 - 0.5, xmax = 3 + 0.5, ymin = 2, ymax = 3, fill = "green")
```

[image]

After you're satisfied with the placement, put `geom_bar` last.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that existed! Found `geom_ribbon` and `geom_area` but not `geom_rect`. That does the job perfectly, thanks very much.